# Compose Appbar overlaps activity content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image: see image,Card overlapping the appbar]

im still learning compose.in this prototype im buiding,my Column containing the card views,in this case 1 dummy card,is overlapping with the appbar. i have tried using scaffold too,same result

here is the Card code:

```
@Composable
fun DiaryCard(){
val bs = "filler text,strings,anything "+
        "jadsjjadj adsnjasjd d saasd" +" sadsad asdasd adsasda" +
        "sasdasdas dsa d"



   Column {
   
   Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp))
   Card(modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxWidth()
       .padding(13.dp),
       shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
       elevation = 5.dp, backgroundColor = Color.White){


       Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 2.dp)){

           Text(text = "29 Sept. 2019", modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth(0.75F)
               .padding(start = 1.5.dp),color = Color.Black)



       }
       Divider()
       Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 3.dp,top = 2.dp))
       Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
           Text(text = "today was a good day",color = Color.Black)
           Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 3.dp))
           Text(text = bs, color = Color.Black)
       }

       }
   }
}
```

The Appbar:

```
    @Composable
     fun topAppbar(){
       TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray) {

      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Add a `Scaffold` with `topBar = { topAppbar() }`
- Add a `Column()` to wrap all the content of the Card

Something like:

```
Scaffold(topBar = { topAppbar() },
) {
    DiaryCard()
}
```

with:

```
@Composable
fun DiaryCard(){

    val bs = "filler text,strings,anything "+
            "jadsjjadj adsnjasjd d saasd" +" sadsad asdasd adsasda" +
            "sasdasdas dsa d"

    Column {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp))
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                //.background(Color.Red)
                .padding(13.dp),
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            elevation = 5.dp, backgroundColor = Color.White
        ) {
            Column() { //It is important to avoid overlap inside the Card

                Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 2.dp)) {

                    Text(
                        text = "29 Sept. 2019", modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(0.75F)
                            .padding(start = 1.5.dp), color = Color.Black
                    )


                }
                Divider()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 3.dp, top = 2.dp))
                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(text = "today was a good day", color = Color.Black)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 3.dp))
                    Text(text = bs, color = Color.Black)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Composable
fun topAppbar(){

    TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray) {
        Text("AppBar")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use innerPadding,

```
 Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    ...
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu Icon" )
                }
            },
            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200),
            contentColor = Color.White,
            elevation = 12.dp
        )
    },

){
    innerPadding ->
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)){
        DiaryCard()
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering what those padding values are for. Thanks a lot. Google has made things so complicated

Answer (score 2):

Since Compose 1.2.0 it's required to use padding parameters, passed into Scaffold content composable. You should apply it to the topmost container/view in the content

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { AppBar() }) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it)) // Add this to fix it
         {
            Content()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That approach has worked.

Answer (score 0):

ATTACHING A CODE SNIPPET FROM MY CODE

```
Scaffold(
            topBar = {Top(onNavigationIconClick = {scope.launch {drawerState.open()}})},
            bottomBar = { Bottom(navController = navController) },
            content= {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) { // THE MODIFIER PARAMETER DOES THE MAGIC
                    Navigation(navController)
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**